# Intel Xeon E5 ES (engineering sample)

Tags: processor

I expect to build a workstation machine based on xeon chip, essentially for having multiple cores and ecc memory. I found on ebay some used xeon E5 chips with low prices, but they are tagged "ES" (engineering samples), or "QS". I searched a bit about these chips, it's said it's illegal to own these chips. They also said that ES chips are not 100% stable, and that's specifically what I'm searching for. ("I don't care" about consumption). They also talk about stepping.

What can you advice ? E3 / E5 / E7 chip ? V1/V2/V3/V4 ? 
Edit : I prefer E5, in order to add a second processor in future. 
Used/not used/ES used ?

Comment: What do you plan on using the workstation for? E.g. video rendering, calculating trajectories, data mining, encryption etc...

Comment: As it stands, your question is pretty broad. There many different Xeon chips differing in processing power, power consumption, support of various hardware (e.g. USB 3.0) etc... Could you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: image treatment (photoshop), Video rendering, 3d rendering, encryption, mathematic algorithms, sql database analysis, usb3 and sata3 needed, and a nice pci express port for quadro graphic card, and windows 10 support

Comment: I guess i need many cores, and single core high frequency

Comment: It is not illegal to own ES chips. It is against Intel's EULA to sell them. I own and use an Intel W3680 ES in my main rig. It is very stable and seems to perform at or slightly above par (I have it OC'd by about 700mhz).